# Can't get my photos and videos from iPad

Tags: itunes, ipad

Here's the situation.

My sister went to Australia to visit our aunt and uncle there. She had my camera, and took a lot of photos and videos. Unfortunately, the camera ran out of memory, and she was forced to get creative.

She used our aunt's Windows 7 PC, and, through iTunes, stored some videos and pictures on her iPad, creating a new folder for it.

Upon getting back home, she tried to extract the pictures and videos from the iPad, but couldn't. She tried:

- Importing it using Windows without iTunes - it's not in any of the folders.
- Importing it using Windows with iTunes - it's also not in any of the folders.
- She also tried it using a Mac with iTunes. She backed it up, and all the photos from the iPad did get copies on the Mac, ***except the folder she created***.

The pictures cannot be edited or deleted in the iPad. She duplicated the album, and found out that the duplicated items can be edited and deleted, but still could not be found from the PC / Mac, backup or otherwise.

Amy suggestions?

Comment: Any chance your Aunt would be willing to Put the pictures on Dropbox? Unless they were deleted they should be easily accessible from that computer. Otherwise, does the Mac and iPad support AirDrop? If so, you could manually select all the images and then AirDrop them to the computer.

Comment: That's Gbs worth of data, so putting up and downloading it would be a problem. The MacBook is a Mid-2013 Retina, and should have AirDrop, though I have no idea how to check for the iPad model, nor if it supports AirDrop.

Comment: Your options are extremely limited. Apple [specifically says](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201313) that you can't sync those iTunes synced photos from your iOS device to your computer. Would iExplorer work, I wonder? https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/tutorials/how-to-save-and-export-photos-from-iphone-ipad-ipod. I haven't used it but it could be worth trying.

Comment: I just found out that the iPad is an iPad 2, and as such, has no AirDrop. I'll give iExplorer a shot, thanks.

Comment: @bassplayer7, does that "You can't import photos or videos synced from iTunes" apply to a duplicate of that album?

Comment: I'm not sure on that.

Comment: @bassplayer7, it's working, thanks. Mind putting it as an answer so I can mark it accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason iTunes photo sync (iOS Device -> Photos) is quite restricted regarding what you do with those photos after they are on the iOS device. Even [Apple specifically](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201313#more) says that you can't sync those photos from your iOS device to your computer.

As a result, I suggest trying [iExplorer](https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) to [copy the photos from the iPad to your computer](https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/tutorials/how-to-save-and-export-photos-from-iphone-ipad-ipod).

If you had AirDrop on both devices, you could use that to transfer the pictures, but it would be a little painstaking as you would have to tap every picture to transfer.